# Problem accessing an object in a particular context

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble accessing a particular object from a certain context.
I have a piece of Javascript that uses `jquery`, moment and `daterangepicker`.

I'm using `jquery` to set an function to run when the `apply.daterangepicker` event fires, and I need to call a method in another object from within that function.
My code looks like this:

```
$('input[name="daterangetext"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(e,picker) {
        pickerStartString = moment(picker.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
        pickerEndString = moment(picker.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
        start = pickerStartString;
        end = pickerEndString;
        changeRange();
});
```

The call to `changeRange` is the problem. I have an object defined as follows:

```
var APG_g = new APGraph('test APGraph Object');
```

The changeRange method is defined as:

```
this.changeRange = function()
{
    function body here
}
```

How do I call `changeRange` from within the above function?
I have tried calling it as `APG_g.changeRange()` but that doesn't work - variables `changeRange` uses internally seem to get unset as I get a runtime error that they are undefined, then subsequent calls to `changeRange` fail for the same reason.

Can anyone explain how I should be doing this?

Comment: Can you add the `changeRange` implementation? What is the exact error you get?

Comment: that's pretty unclear what you are asking

Comment: *Where* is the `var APG_g` defined? Please post the complete code as a whole

Comment: It seems you could call `changeRange` like so, assuming the variable referencing that object is in scope. `APG_g.changeRange()`.

Comment: this.changeRange appears to be part of another object. to access it you should use the parent object's name. for example if the parent object is called `range` you should use `range.changeRange();` It also appears that your not defining your variables correctly. Assuming you're using ES6, variables should be preceded by either `const` (for variables that don't change, also called constants) or `let` for variables that do change. You're also reassigning pickerStartString to start and pickerEndString to end - there is no conceivable reason to do this. [edit: grammar]

Comment: Please show us how exactly these functions are currently written, and how they are in relation to each other. JavaScript has very peculiar (some might even say "unorthodox") scoping rules, and trying to pinpoint your problem from this is bit hard. Have you even defined start and end anywhere (with var keyword)?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this little demo will clear things up for you. It doesn't appear you're using ES6 syntax, so the JavaScript I've added uses the older syntax. The idea is to show you how to call a method from a particular context, like you asked.

```js
var button = $('button');

function Test() {
  this.testMethod = function() {
    button.html('New button text');
  }
}

var myTest = new Test();

button.on('click', function handleClick() {
  myTest.testMethod();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <button>Click to change text</button>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zt2ohs7j/

Comment: That's exactly how I thought it should work, but for some reason my code doesn't work properly when I use the equivalent of your 'myTest.testMethod()' suggestion. I think I need to go and have another look at this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments folks. It turns out I had just made a mess of the code. I've got it working now. The correct solution, as Andy Hoffman alluded to, is simply to call the method as APG_g.changeRange();